# Scala: type inference issue

Tags: scala, type-inference, existential-type, type-deduction

I have:

```
sealed trait Par[A]{def foo = ???}
case class Unit[A](v: () => A) extends Par[A]
case class Map2[L, R, A](parLeft: Par[L],
                         parRight: Par[R],
                         map: (L, R) => A) extends Par[A]
```

my problem is that when I pattern match on `p:Par[A]` to do something like this:

```
def getSequentially: A = this match {
  case Par.Unit(f) => f()
  case Par.Map2(a, b, f) => f(a.getSequentially, b.getSequentially)
}
```

`L` and `R` are inferred to be `Any` in Intellij's type inspector and `getSequentially` calls are highlighted in red, warning: `type mismatch, expected Nothing, actual Any`, since `f` is expected to be of type: `(Nothing, Nothing) => A`. Although it actually runs and compiles.

I think I understand what the problem is and I should be able to solve it with existential types in the definition of `Map2`. Only problem is that the `map` parameter has a dependent type, so I don't know how to do that. Maybe I should do a variation of the AUX pattern?

My question is, firstly why it compiles and secondly, if there is a way of restructuring the type dependency so that it no longer issues a warning.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have existentials you can use typed patterns:

```
sealed trait Par[A]{
  def getSequentially: A = this match {
    case x: Par.Unit[A] => x.v()
    case x: Par.Map2[_, _, A] => x.map(x.parLeft.getSequentially, x.parRight.getSequentially)
  }
}

object Par {
  case class Unit[A](v: () => A) extends Par[A]
  case class Map2[L, R, A](parLeft: Par[L],
                           parRight: Par[R],
                           map: (L, R) => A) extends Par[A]
}
```

IntelliJ seems not to highlight this.

Comment: thanks! Out of curiosity, what's the longhand version of `Par.Map2[_, _, A]`? ie how do I write a `forSome` expression with two types`L` and `R` ?

Comment: `Par.Map2[_, _, A]` is `Par.Map2[L, R, A] forSome { type L; type R }`. But you can write it in this form in type position like in `def foo[A](x: Par.Map2[L, R, A] forSome { type L; type R }) = ???`. In our case `Par.Map2[_, _, A]` is not a type, it's a *type pattern* (see [here](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns) starting from "• A parameterized type pattern `T[a1,…,an]` ...") so you can't write it here with `forSome`.